# Check Array of Objects to See if a Specific Property Matches a Condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have data where a `Report` has an array of `Expenses`, and each `Expense` has an array of `Returns`. I want to check each `Return` to see if it satisfies a certain condition. This works:

```
for (var expense of vm.report.Expenses) {
  if (text === "Process") { break; }
  if (expense.Returns.some(x => x.ExpenseReportId === vm.report.Id)) {
    text = "Process";
  }
};
```

However, that feels like an old way of doing things. I've tried `concat`, `map`, etc., but can't seem to get it. I just want something like this:

```
if (report.Expenses.Returns.some(x => ...))
```

I can't do that because `Expenses` is an array, and so is `Returns`. How can I easily check all of the `Returns` properties on all of the `Expense` properties of the `Report`?

Comment: can you post the JSON data structure you are using?

Comment: @skellertor I started typing it and it became a mess. Basically, a Report has many Expenses, and each Expense has many Returns. I want to check a property on each Return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested `Array.some()`. When the predicate in the inner some returns `true`, both some loops would end, and return `true`.

Example (not tested):

```
if(vm.report.Expenses.some(e => 
  e.Returns.some(x => x.ExpenseReportId === vm.report.Id)
)) {
  text = 'Process';
}
```